# C++ HelloWorld program compiled with MinGW crashes with "Illegal Argument"

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I decided it was time that I learned C++, and after struggling for 3+ hours trying to get the compiler to work, I finally created a working program. However, it seemingly spontaneously broke when I tried to refactor the project in Eclipse by cutting and pasting it. The program simply crashes, and Windows brings up the dreaded dialogue "HelloWorld.exe has stopped working." A bit of debugging revealed that "cout" was considered an illegal argument. I looked some more into the issue, and I'm now suspicious that it has something to do with the compiler apparently being 32-bit, as I have a 64-bit system. The executable is listed in Eclipse as "HelloWorld.exe - [x86/le]." (Minus the period.) My program in full is below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've also just discovered that creating a new "HelloWorld" C++ project in Eclipse does absolutely nothing to fix the issue, even using the unmodified code and settings. Anyone have any suggestions as to why this would happen?

EDIT: Debugging information:
Upon running the program:

```
Hello World!
Program received signal SIGNILL, Illegal instruction.
0x6fccc3c0 in libstdc++-6!_ZSt4cout ()
    from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\libstdc++-6.dll
(gdb) bt
#0   0x6fccc3c0 in libstdc++-6~_ZSt4cout ()
    from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\libstdc++-6.dll
#1   0x6fc8908c in libstdc++-6~_ZSt4cout ()
    from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\libstdc++-6.dll
#2   0x004013be in libstdc++-6~_ZSt4cout () at HelloWorld.cpp:4
(gdb)
```

It should be noted that line 4 of the class now points to the cout call.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is considered bad form. Use Google to find out why. There's nothing inherently wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: The most likely cause is some kind of ABI-related issue- your program is clearly valid (although for reference, `using namespace std;` is a terrible practice). There is no problem with a 32bit compiler or executable on a 64bit system. Eclipse simply must not be set up correctly.

Comment: My immediate advice would be to either compile from the command line (e.g., using MinGW) or else install Visual Studio. Getting Eclipse to work correctly under Windows can be challenging even for experienced programmers.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Compiling from the command line provides no change in terms of the application crashing. Putting the compiled app back into Eclipse and debugging reveals that it's (unsurprisingly) due to the same "Illegal Operation" error. Does this mean that the problem is with wrong with either MinGW or Msys?

Comment: @mproncace: if that isn't working when you compile from the command line, then yes, you almost certainly have a problem with your compiler installation. Quick check though: are you sure you ran the right thing?Unless you specify otherwise, `MinGW` will produce an output named `a.exe` -- is that what you ran?

Comment: @JerryCoffin I changed the directory to my Desktop (which is where I put the .cpp file) and ran "g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.exe". I'm reinstalling MiniGW right now; I'll see if that fixes it...
Nope, nothing changed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you are describing. Which MinGW distro are you using? There are a few variations out there.

Comment: Can you run this through gdb and show what the backtrace look like? Compile w/ debug symbols `g++ -O0 -g helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe`. Then run `gdb HelloWorld.exe`. From the interactive gdb prompt type `cont`. When it crashes type `bt` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @greatwolf I've added it to the OP.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. I tried installing and compiling with Visual Studio from the command line, and got the exact same outcome. I truly was not expecting that.

Comment: Shoot, one minute late to edit my last comment. Visual Studio's GUI doesn't seem to cause any problems, so I may just use it instead. I don't think it's worth the stress to get Eclipse working.

Comment: @mproncace it looks like `libstdc++.dll` isn't compatible with the mingw used to compile the program. Maybe one of the past mingw installs polluted it's own runtime libraries in `C:\Windows`? Open a new cmd.exe prompt and set the `Path` environment to your current `mingw\bin` install directory. Then try running `helloworld.exe` again. If it runs to completion then that's the problem in which case you should remove the `libstdc++.dll` from windows\syswow64.

Comment: @greatwolf Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case. The program still fails to complete even after executing from the MinGW bin directory.

Comment: @greatwolf Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. I thought you wanted me to compile from the MinGW directory. But, regardless, launching from that directory doesn't seem to work either. EDIT: Removing libstdv++.dll seems to have done the trick anyway. If you post you comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at your gdb backtrace, the problem appears to be an incompatible C++ runtime `libstdc++.dll`.

This could happen if you're installing MinGW over an existing install. Another way this could happen is if some other third party program needing `libstdc++.dll` installed its dependencies into your `Windows\SysWow64` so it could be found system wide. The issue is of course, differing versions of the `libstdc++` aren't compatible with each other at the ABI level. Programs compiled with a given Mingw g++ version needs to load the *corresponding* `libstdc++.dll` that came with that particular Mingw install.

Open a new cmd.exe prompt and *set* the Path environment to your current `mingw\bin` install directory. For example, if your mingw install is in `c:\mingw32-4.7.2`:

```
C:\>set path=C:\mingw32-4.7.2\bin
```

Then try running helloworld.exe again. If it runs to completion without crashing then that is likely the problem. In this case you should remove the libstdc++.dll from `windows\syswow64`.

Comment: @mproncace yw, these things can be really annoying to track down. MSVC is slightly better in that regard since Microsoft actually gives their different runtime version different names. That's how you end up with MSVCRxx.dll redistributables.

Comment: Just ran into this problem, but couldn't find libstdc++.dll in the windows\syswow64. Linking statically, as defined below, resolved it (although it isn't really a fix if you can't dynamically link, if you need to).

Comment: @trayres in recent versions of mingw (4.6.3 and later) it's actually named `libstdc++-6.dll`. You can find it under your respective mingw/bin directory.

Comment: Thanks @greatwolf
For those that come later:
I changed the environment variable PATH within Eclipse to just C:/MinGW/bin, and that took care of the different versions and allowed me to launch from Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Build it statically so you don't have to worry about wrong depencies. Just add "-static" to your Compiler-options.