# Piping a data file with cat to a C++ program

Tags: c++, pipe, cat

I'm looking for some help piping a file (16-bit signed little endian integers raw data) from the command line to my program:

```
cat data.dat | myprogram
```

Then it should convert the data to 16 bit signed integers.
It works for the first 12 values. The 13th value is wrong, followed by zeros.

The second problem is that the program seems to enter the while loop only once.

I am using Windows + MinGW.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define DEFAULT_BUF_LENGTH (16 * 16384)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    char buf[DEFAULT_BUF_LENGTH];

    while(cin >> buf) 
    {
        int16_t* data = (int16_t*) buf; //to int

        for(int i=0;i<18;i++)
        {
            cout << data[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
9621
-14633
-264
5565
-12288
9527
-7109
11710
6351
4096
-5033
5773
147
0
0
0
0
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Piping for input/output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508626/piping-for-input-output)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1599093/4074081) discussion. On Windows stdin is opened in text mode and certain byte indicates end of file, the solution is to reopen it in binary mode.

Comment: You can't use `>>` it converts line endings. You have to use **unformatted input** functions like `cin.read()`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try to use `read()` instead of the `>>` operator, which is generally for formatted input. Also checking how much data was actually read is useful:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define DEFAULT_BUF_LENGTH (16 * 16384)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    char buf[DEFAULT_BUF_LENGTH];

    for(;;) 
    {
        cin.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
        int size = cin.gcount();
        if (size == 0) break;

        int16_t* data = (int16_t*) buf; //to int

        for(int i=0;i<size/sizeof(int16_t);i++)
        {
            cout << hex << data[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second problem is still be there, the program only prints the first 12 values. I forgot to mention that I compile my programs with `g++ myprogram.cpp -static -o myprogram`. Perhaps this is the reason? If I compile my program without the -static flag it crashes after execution (APPCRASH: Error Module Name: libstdc++-6.dll). I found no solution for this problem, but I think it has something to do with 64bit Windows. On Linux your code works as expected.

Comment: Would be useful to have your input file

Comment: Even a simple helloworld.cpp program crashes if I do not set the `-static` flag. I think my MinGW is broken. My Problem is similar to that one: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157464/c-helloworld-program-compiled-with-mingw-crashes-with-illegal-argument] but there is no `libstdc++.dll ` in `windows\syswow64` which I could delete...

Comment: I uploaded a test file for you: http://www.filedropper.com/rawdata   do you also use MinGW + 64bit Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Statement `cin >> buf` does **not** fill the whole `buf` with data. It reads only next "set" of non-whitespace characters.
Change `cin >> buf` to `read(0, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0`

If you insist on using C++ streams, change beginning of your loop to:

```
while (!cin.eof()) {
    cin.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
    [...]
```

Comment: I agree with the diagnosis; that is the problem.  I'm not convinced the suggested remedy is the best option.  There are, surely, ways to read binary data from `cin` rather than falling back on POSIX file descriptor functions like `read()`, which would require the `<unistd.h>` header too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, sometimes using ol' good C is simpler ;)